# Homomorphism from trivial group to $\mathbb{Z}_{5n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm looking to find a homomorphism from trivial group to $\mathbb{Z}_{5n}$. Is it simple as $$g: e \to \mathbb{Z}_{5n}, g(x) = 5n$$

Because $$g(1) = g(1 \cdot 1)  = 5n = 0 (\text{mod 5n})$$
and $$g(1) \oplus g(1) = 5n + 5n = 0 (\text{mod 5n})$$

And the identity is preserved with this homomorphism. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Yup, this is the only possibility. Though I have to ask why would you not define it as the constant map to $0$?

Comment: Wait so suppose the trivial group undergoes multiple homomorphisms to different groups. Could I just identify the functions of these homomorphisms as just a map to the identity of each group (cause homomorphisms preserve identity)?

Comment: Given a group $G$, there is one and only one homomorphism from the trivial group to $G$, and one and only one homomorphism from $G$ to the trivial group. It’s not a question of “identifying” anything: two homomorphisms are equal if they are equal as functions, and they are equal as functions if and only if they have the same domain, the same codomain, and the same value at every point of the domain. Morphisms from $\{e\}$ to different groups are different morphisms, because they are different functions, because they have different codomains.

Comment: If the trivial group first underwent a homomorphism $g_1$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{5n}$ and then a homomorphism $g_2$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{5n}$ to the Dihedral group where $n = 5$, would $g_1$ be a constant map to $1$ and $g_2$ a constant map to $1$ again?

Comment: @J.Cricks You don't tell us what $g_2$ is, so we don't know. *Any* homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{5n}$ to $D_{5}$ will necessarily send the trivial subgroup to the trivial subgroup. The **composition** $g_2\circ g_1$ is the (unique) map from the trivial group to $D_5$, which sends "everything" (just one thing, really, so it is a bit silly to call it "a constant map", though it technically satisfies the definition) to the identity element. So?

Comment: It is a sequence of homomorphisms: $1 \to \mathbb{Z}_5 \to D_5$ and $g_1$ and $g_2$ is unknown. But I assumed $g2$ would be a constant map to the identity in $D_5$ considering the trivial group only maps to the identity in $Z_5$

Comment: @J.Cricks: Sorry, but that’s nonsense. The *composite* is trivial, but there is absolutely no warrant for even beginning to think that $g_2$ must be trivial. There is absolutely no reason to assume it would be. If the sequence is said to be “exact”, then it **definitely** is not, because that means the kernel of $g_2$ is required to be the image of $g_1$, which is the trivial subgroup. Sorry, but you are utterly confused and lost.

Comment: @J.Cricks: Note that there are only a handful of maps $\mathbb{Z}_5\to D_5$: basically, you must map into the cyclic group of order $5$ inside $D_5$. If this is generated by $r$, then you must send the generator of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ to $r^i$ for some $i$, $0\leq i\leq 4$. Frankly, I think you are completely misunderstanding what you are being told, and because of that you are not describing the situation accurately.